# Jquery ajax with parent ajax.done

Tags: jquery

Are there issues that prevent a jquery ajax call from being executed properly if it is nested within the .done() method of a parent ajax request?  It seems that the .done() of the nested ajax call does not get executed.  Thanks so much for whatever help you can provide.

```
var findNearestFacility = function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $addrsInput = $("form[data-ucw-ajaxNearestFacility] input.nearest-facility-input").attr('value')

    var geocoderInput = new google.maps.Geocoder();


    ////// calculate longitude and latitude for address entered in
    geocoderInput.geocode({ 'address': $addrsInput }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            latitudeUser = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitudeUser = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            var facilities = [];

            var facilitiesAndDistance = new Array();

            var options = {
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Facilities/AllFacilities'
            };

            $.ajax(options).done(function (data1) {

                $.each(data1, function () {
                    this.ConcatAddress = this.StreetAddress1 + ", " + this.City + ", " + this.State + ", " + this.Zip;
                    facilities.push(this);
                });

                maxLengthFacilities = facilities.length;  // store max length of array

                var length = facilities.length;

                for (var indexFacility = 0; indexFacility < length; indexFacility++) {

                    var currentAddress = facilities[indexFacility].ConcatAddress;

                    geoCode(facilities[indexFacility], indexFacility, latitudeUser, longitudeUser);

                }

                var i = facilities;

                var facilitiesJson = $.toJSON(facilities);

                var options2 = {
                    url: "/Home/NearestFacilities",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: facilitiesJson
                };

                $.ajax(options2).done(function (returnData) {
                    // HELP!!
                    // CODE IN THIS BLOCK NEVER EXECUTES

                    alert('x');

                    //var $target = $($form.attr('data-ucw-target'));
                    //var $newHtml = $(data2);
                    //$target.replaceWith($newHtml);
                    //$target.effect('highlight');

                    //alert(data2);
                });

            })
        };
    });


    return false;
}
```

Update: Thanks for suggesting to simplifiy the code as it is revealing.  Below is a simplified version.  This test works as expected so the question becomes what is wrong with the original code.

```
var nestedAjexTest = function () {
        var options = {
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Facilities/Ajax1'
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data1) {
            alert("done1 " + data1);

            var options2 = {
                url: "/Facilities/Ajax2",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data1
            };

            $.ajax(options2).done(function (data2) {
                alert("done2 " + data2);
            })


        })

        return false;
    };
```

Comment: Does the nested ajax request even fire? Do you get a response from the server?

Comment: yes it fires.  I can see it execute in my mvc controller in debug mode.  i never get the alert('x') message

Comment: What about a response; does your browser debugger show a response from the server?

Comment: Yes indeed I do.  IE F12 Web Tool show a response body containing the HTML I need to replace a <div> on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent some time looking into this situation and I'm unable to either replicate or diagnose the issue. See the following working example of a nested ajax request using the deferred methods.

```
$.ajax().done(function(){
   $.ajax().done(function() {
       console.warn('success');
   });
});
```

I would suggest removing snippets of your code until your nested `done()` fires correctly. There is a chance that geocoder is *somehow* interfering, but pending a javascript error, I don't see how.

Comment: Much  appreciated by your efforts. Unfortunately I have boiled down my line commenting down to the simplest alert('x')

Comment: I believe now that the options2 object specifies json which is why it is not working.  The result set is html so I must have overlooked that datatype option being set.